# IDL syntax error in genrand2d.pro

Tags: idl-programming-language

I'm not very familiar with IDL, but am trying to run a code given to me by a colleague. I'm getting strange syntax errors in the generic code snippet genrand2d.pro (downloaded from [here](https://git.ias.u-psud.fr/abeelen/idl_libs/tree/ffb40bbfb06381b4f292c2332bdba858de735374/sdssidl/pro/statistics)) which is preventing the whole thing from running. It's possible that it's a version syntax change thing, since my colleague has IDL version 6.3 while I have 8.6.0 (on Scientific Linux 7.2) but I haven't been able to find a list of syntax changes or similar to check.

The line causing problems is:

```
randx = arrscl(randomu(seed, nbad, /double), $ 
                     minx, maxx, $ 
                     arrmin=0d, arrmax=1d )
```

And the error message:

```
                     arrmin=0d, arrmax=1d )
                            ^
% Syntax error.
  At: /generic/path/genrand2d.pro, Line 114
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that IDL is confused on whether `arrscl` is an array or a function. To test if this is the case, compile `arrscl`, recompile `genrand2d`, and then try again.

In general, to fix these errors use `compile_opt strictarr` in all your routines and always use square brackets for array indexing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In trying to follow your advice I found the problem: I didn't have arrscl.pro at all, and the syntax error was preventing IDL from flagging it as missing.